# Can you apply names in OpenOffice Calc the same way you can in Excel?

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice-calc

In Excel, you can apply names to a formula (semi)automatically by selecting the formula/formulae in question and then using the Apply Names function.

This will change something like `=B3+C9*D16` into `=BaseCost+NumberOfInstances*CostPerInstance`, assuming B3, C9, and D16 are named accordingly.

Note that I'm not asking for a feature to name cell ranges, but the Apply Names function which automatically apply names to existing formulae that just uses cell references.

Is there a similar function in Calc? It seems that most of Excel's other Name-related features are there, but this one, I haven't seen...

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed.

What you are looking for is called a "Named Range"

[This guide](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Creating_named_ranges) talks you through the process, but essentially its:

1. Select the cell range and click Insert > Names > Define to open the Define Names window
2. Enter the name for the range in the Name field.
3. Click OK to close the window.

Comment: This was not my question. I asked if you can apply the names to a formula, not whether you can define the names.